# Url rewrite is not redirecting to https

Tags: redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I have a url rewrite in my web.config that is supposed to redirect some urls to https while ignoring some other urls.

Here is what I currently have:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.qa.mysite.com" negate="true" />
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="dev1.qa.mysite.com" negate="false" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
       </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I works as expected by not redirecting localhost and all *.qa.mysite.com urls. It also redirects dev1.qa.mysite.com to https as expected.

The issue is that I want dashboard.mysite.com to be automatically redirected https, and I cannot figure out how to make that work.

If I add,

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="dashboard.mysite.com" negate="false" />
```

, it does not work.

Any idea what am I missing?